# HTML: Place DIV content side by side without overlapping

Tags: html, css, user-interface

As you can see below, I have three boxes. You can see that in box 1 and 3 everything works great, but in box 2 the text content is overlapping.

This is because of the `<div>` with the class `.vertical_center.grade_info` has the `margin-left` option for only `100px`. I don't want these intersections.

How do I change `margin-left` for all boxes individually to avoid this problem?

Here are my code so far:

```css
.three_separation {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 60px;
}

.grades_dashboard_box {
  height: 130px;
  width: 320px;
  background-color: #0d0d0d;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.grade_display {
  float: left;
  font-size: 60px;
}

.vertical_center {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="three_separation">
  <div class='grades_dashboard_box'>
    <div class="vertical_center">
      <h1 class="grade_display" id="grade_display_best">2.3</h1>
      <div class="vertical_center grade_info" style="margin-left: 100px;">
        <p style="font-size: 15px;">Beste Durchschnittsnote</p>
        <p id="grade_display_best_sub" style="font-size: 20px;">Biologie</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='grades_dashboard_box'>
    <div class="vertical_center">
      <h1 class="grade_display" id="grade_display_average">13.70</h1>
      <div class="vertical_center grade_info" style="margin-left: 100px;">
        <p style="font-size: 15px;">Durchschnittsnote</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='grades_dashboard_box'>
    <div class="vertical_center">
      <h1 class="grade_display" id="grade_display_worst">3.4</h1>
      <div class="vertical_center grade_info" style="margin-left: 100px;">
        <p style="font-size: 15px;">Schlechteste Durchschnittsnote</p>
        <p id="grade_display_worst_sub" style="font-size: 20px;">Deutsch</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `box-sizing: border-box`?

Comment: @Ivan Rubinson How to use this for my example? simply add `box-sizing: border-box` to `vertical_center grade_info`??

Comment: Read a bit about what `box-sizing: border-box` does and apply it where you think is relevant. You described an issue with `margin`s, which `box-sizing: border-box` comes to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could use [flex-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) to achieve the consistent layout that you require, by updating your CSS as follows:

```css
.grade_display {
  font-size: 60px;
}

/* Add this */
.grades_dashboard_box>div {
  /* Use flex box on the first div of .grades_dashboard_box */
  display: flex;
  /* Cause flex layout axis on this div to be horizontal */
  flex-direction: row;
  /* Cause children to center vertically */
  align-items: center;
}

/* Add this (replaces inline margin-left style) */
.grades_dashboard_box .grade_info {
  /* Add space to left of .grade_info */
  margin-left: 40px;
  /* Limit width to break small text onto two lines */
  width: 100px;
}


/* Add this */
.grades_dashboard_box h1 {
  /* Replace h1's default margin to enable vertical centering */
  margin: 0;
}

.three_separation {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 60px;
}

.grades_dashboard_box {
  height: 130px;
  width: 320px;
  background-color: #0d0d0d;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  /* Add this */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- remove margin-left:100px throughout -->
<div class="three_separation">
  <div class='grades_dashboard_box'>
    <div class="vertical_center">
      <h1 class="grade_display" id="grade_display_best">2.3</h1>
      <div class="vertical_center grade_info">
        <p style="font-size: 15px;">Beste Durchschnittsnote</p>
        <p id="grade_display_best_sub" style="font-size: 20px;">Biologie</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='grades_dashboard_box'>
    <div class="vertical_center">
      <h1 class="grade_display" id="grade_display_average">13.70</h1>
      <div class="vertical_center grade_info">
        <p style="font-size: 15px;">Durchschnittsnote</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='grades_dashboard_box'>
    <div class="vertical_center">
      <h1 class="grade_display" id="grade_display_worst">3.4</h1>
      <div class="vertical_center grade_info">
        <p style="font-size: 15px;">Schlechteste Durchschnittsnote</p>
        <p id="grade_display_worst_sub" style="font-size: 20px;">Deutsch</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```